# how can I improve my plot and basemap overlay?

Tags: r, plot

I have a basic plot of rainfall contours with a map overlay.
1.  I wonder if there is something I can change on the aspect ratio so 
that my map is proportional. Furthermore I am wondering why the frame 
disregards the map limits that I set.
2.  Is there an extrapolation function I can add so that I can improve 
my plot and fill the map area with contours, even if it means filling 
the whole plotting frame.
Help will be appreciated. My code is below.

## Libraries

```
library(maps)  
library(akima)
```

## Set working directory and get data

```
setwd("C:/R_Progs/Scripts")  
datr <- read.table("./RFMEAN.DAT",header=TRUE,sep="")  
datfr <- data.frame(datr)  
x <- datfr[,1]  
y <- datfr[,2]  
z <- datfr[,3]
```

## Interpolation

```
fld <- with(datfr, interp(x , y, z))
```

## Make the plot

```
filled.contour(x = fld$x, y = fld$y, z = fld$z,  
plot.axes = {axis(1); axis(2); map('world', xlim = c(21, 34), ylim =  
c(-19, -8), add = T, col = "darkgrey")},  
color.palette = colorRampPalette(c("white", "blue")),  
xlab = "Longitude",  
ylab = "Latitude",  
main = "Zambian rainfall",  
key.title = title(main = "Rain (mm)", cex.main = 1))
```

## My data

```
Lon      Lat   Rain  
32.58   -13.55  1016.9  
27.07   -16.85  801.6  
32.67   -10.17  1090  
24.2    -13.6   1034.4  
28.47   -14.45  907.7  
28.5    -14.4   917.7  
28.12   -12.6   1309.1  
27.92   -15.77  761.4  
22.7    -14.    825.2  
24.8    -14.8   902.4  
31.13   -10.22  1343.2  
25.85   -13.53  1146.8  
29.08    -9.8   1378.6  
25.82   -17.82  691.7  
33.2    -12.28  922.9  
28.32   -15.42  1078.1  
28.45   -15.3   882.1  
27.63   -16.13  737.3  
28.85   -11.1   1176.6  
31.33    -8.85  1267.8  
31.93   -13.27  817.5  
31.22   -10.18  1349.7  
23.15   -15.25  918.2  
31.43   -11.9   1040  
32.56   -13.65  1011.7  
28.25   -15.55  856.7  
27.07   -14.98  891.2  
24.43   -11.75  1413.1  
28.65   -13.    1232.8  
31.28   -14.25  966.8  
29.53   -11.35  1476.5  
23.27   -16.12  729.7  
30.22   -13.23  1133.6  
24.3    -17.47  756.3  
26.38   -12.18  1309.7  
23.12   -13.53  1057.4
```

## And the plot I get (I hope it is uploaded)

[image: Zambian Rainfall]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't extrapolate outside your data range, so no there is no way to fill the entire map unless you want to make up data.

I like `ggmap` much better. Maybe you can try/start with this and mess around.

```
library(ggmap)
z = get_map(location = "Zambia", color = "bw", zoom = 6)
ggmap(z, extent = "normal", maprange=FALSE) +
  stat_density2d(data = df, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = Rain, fill = ..level..),
                 geom="polygon", bins = 100, size = 0.01, alpha = 0.05) +
                 scale_fill_gradient(name = "Rainfall", low = "dodgerblue", high = "dodgerblue4")
```

Edit for Comment

Run this in case your df is different.

`df=structure(list(Lon = c(32.58, 27.07, 32.67, 24.2, 28.47, 28.5, 
28.12, 27.92, 22.7, 24.8, 31.13, 25.85, 29.08, 25.82, 33.2, 28.32, 
28.45, 27.63, 28.85, 31.33, 31.93, 31.22, 23.15, 31.43, 32.56, 
28.25, 27.07, 24.43, 28.65, 31.28, 29.53, 23.27, 30.22, 24.3, 
26.38, 23.12), Lat = c(-13.55, -16.85, -10.17, -13.6, -14.45, 
-14.4, -12.6, -15.77, -14, -14.8, -10.22, -13.53, -9.8, -17.82, 
-12.28, -15.42, -15.3, -16.13, -11.1, -8.85, -13.27, -10.18, 
-15.25, -11.9, -13.65, -15.55, -14.98, -11.75, -13, -14.25, -11.35, 
-16.12, -13.23, -17.47, -12.18, -13.53), Rain = c(1016.9, 801.6, 
1090, 1034.4, 907.7, 917.7, 1309.1, 761.4, 825.2, 902.4, 1343.2, 
1146.8, 1378.6, 691.7, 922.9, 1078.1, 882.1, 737.3, 1176.6, 1267.8, 
817.5, 1349.7, 918.2, 1040, 1011.7, 856.7, 891.2, 1413.1, 1232.8, 
966.8, 1476.5, 729.7, 1133.6, 756.3, 1309.7, 1057.4)), .Names = c("Lon", 
"Lat", "Rain"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))`
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Vlo, this will be very useful though currently am getting the following message Map from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?  center=Zambia&zoom=6&size=%20640x640&scale=%202&maptype=terrain&sensor=false  Google Maps API Terms of Service : http://developers.google.com/maps/terms  Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?  address=Zambia&sensor=false  Google Maps API Terms of Service : http://developers.google.com/maps/terms  Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class function. I will work with this and see how far I get.

Comment: See edit. Too long for comment. Try running the `df`. Run the code line by line, which line does it error? Does it error at `ggmap(z...`?

Comment: Thanks once more @Vlo. When I run it line by line with my code the error is at "fld <- with(interp(x , y, z))", with the error "(Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "interp". So I can always format my data to run according to what you have given me. But then why are the values so small (scale .005-.015) and what does row.names = c(NA, -36L))?

Comment: ....so you don't have this `interp` function, which seems to be from `library(akima)`. Do you have that library? If you are trying to use `ggmap` then you don't need any of this `interp` or `filled.contour` stuff.

Comment: I actually load akima, and on the packages I do not see interp. I think I can work with your code and forget about interp. But can you clarify why I cannot get the values plotted without scaling down, i.e. 100's not .005?

Comment: `stat_density2d()` is estimating the density of `Rain` at each `Lon/Lat`. The estimated density is not on the same scale as the original `Rain (mm)`. There is probably some way of changing the scaling or display, but I don't know how to do it on the top of my head.

Comment: next time you read this and hove some time advise me why the data values are plotted as very small values (from the scale), otherwise the    stat_density2d    function works very well but I was expecting the plot to reflect the data distribution.